# Does gcc support 128-bit int on amd64?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, 128-bit, extended-precision

Does gcc support 128-bit int on amd64?

How to define it?

How to use scanf/printf to read/write it?

Comment: How to print at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc

Comment: Which versions of GCC support it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329541/does-gcc-support-128-bit-int-on-amd64

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) supports built-in `__int128` and `unsigned __int128` types (on 64-bit platforms only), but it looks like formatting support for 128-bit integers is less common in libc.

Note: `<stdint.h>` defines `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` on versions before gcc4.6.  See also [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc/54815033#54815033) for a table of gcc/clang/ICC versions.

[How to know if __uint128_t is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531782/how-to-know-if-uint128-t-is-defined) for detecting `__int128`

Comment: The types on more recent versions are `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`.

Answer (score 15):

```
void f(__int128* res, __int128* op1, __int128* op2)
{
    *res = *op1 + *op2;
}
```

Save to test.c and compile with:

```
$ gcc -c -O3 test.c
$ objdump -d -M intel test.o
```

You get:

```
mov    rcx, rdx
mov    rax, [rsi]
mov    rdx, [rsi+0x8]

add    rax, [rcx]
adc    rdx, [rcx+0x8]

mov    [rdi], rax
mov    [rdi+0x8], rdx
```

As you can see the `__int128` type is supported by keeping two 64-bits in sequence and then operating on them with the typical big int pattern of using two instructions, for example ADD and then ADC (add with carry)

Comment: Does hardware support exist at all?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: add and adc is like 2 ticks.  A single instruction like DIV is like 50 ticks.  Shrug.