# Big integer numbers & C

Tags: c++, biginteger, arbitrary-precision

I am writing a program which generates big integer numbers, saves them in an array, and does some basic operations such as multiply or add.

I'm really worried about the performance of the actual code and would like tips or improvements to make it faster. Any suggestion is welcome, even if it changes my whole program or data types.

I will add below some piece of code, in order that you can see the structures that I am using and how I'm trying to deal with this B.I.N.:

```
unsigned int seed;


void initCharArray( char *L, unsigned N )
{
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    L[i] = i%50;
  }
}


char Addition( char *Vin1, char *Vin2, char *Vout, unsigned N )
{
  char CARRY = 0;
  for ( int i=0; i< N; i++ ) 
  {
    char R = Vin1[i] + Vin2[i] + CARRY;
    if ( R <= 9 )
    {
      Vout[i] = R; CARRY = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      Vout[i] = R-10; CARRY = 1;
    }
  }
  return CARRY;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int N=10000;
unsigned char *V1=new int[N];
unsigned char *V2=new int[N];
unsigned char *V3=new int[N];

initCharArray(V1,N); initCharArray(V2,N);

Addition(V1,V2,V3,N);
}
```

Comment: Use a larger base, such as base 2^64 instead of base 10, where each digit is something like `uint64_t`. If the numbers you're dealing with are really large you can look into using the FFT to multiply them.

Comment: @BessieTheCow The base 10 numbers is mandatory for this project, thank you for that advice even so. I will try that FFT method as other user also recommended to achieve that (nlog(n)) complexity. Do you have any webpage where I can read some "newbie" info about it? A lot of thanks for your time.

Comment: The efficient way is to use a limb that's equal to the register size, i.e. base 2³² or 2⁶⁴ on 32/64-bit computers. See [Why to use higher base for implementing BigInt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10178055/995714), [How are extremely large floating-point numbers represented in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23840565/995714). Every good library like GMP or Boost.Multiprecision has already been written very efficiently using base 2³² or 2⁶⁴ instead base 10

Comment: The FFT is only faster for really big numbers, and it's also very advanced, so I definitely don't recommend attempting it in a school project if you've never dealt with this kind of algorithms and math before. If you really want to learn the FFT (again, you very probably shouldn't at this point), you could try looking at the Wikipedia page and searching for other tutorials online, but the best explanation that I know of is from the CLRS book.

Comment: [*"In practice the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm starts to outperform older methods such as Karatsuba and Toom–Cook multiplication for numbers beyond 2^2^15 to 2^2^17 (10,000 to 40,000 decimal) digits"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) so FFT won't help unless you have huge numbers as BessieTheCow said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since modern possessors are highly efficient when dealing with fixed bit length numbers why don't you have an array of them?

Suppose you use `unsigned long long`. They should be 64 bits width, so max possible `unsigned long long` should be `2^64 - 1`. Lets represent any number as a collection of numbers as:

-`big_num = ( n_s, n_0, n_1, ...)`

-`n_s` will take only 0 and 1 to represent + and - sign

-`n_0` will represent number between 0 and 10^a -1 (exponent a to be determent)

-`n_1` will represent number between 10^a and 10^(a+1) -1
and so on, and so on ...

DETERMINING a:

All `n_` MUST be bounded by `10^a-1`. Thus when adding two `big_num` this means we need to add the `n_` as follow:

```
// A + B = ( (to be determent later),
//          bound(n_A_1 + n_B_1) and carry to next,
//          bound(n_A_2 + n_B_2 + carry) and carry to next,
//        ...)
```

The bounding can be done as:

`bound(n_A_i + n_B_i + carry) = (n_A_i + n_B_i + carry)%(10^a)`

Therefore the carry to `i+1` is determined as:

```
// carry (to be used in i+1) = (n_A_i + n_B_i + carry)/(10^a) 
// (division of unsigned in c++ will floor the result by construction)
```

This tell us that the worst case is `carry = 10^a -1`, and thus the worst addition `(n_A_i + n_B_i + carry)` is:
`(worst case) (10^a-1) + (10^a-1) + (10^a-1) = 3*(10^a-1)`
Since type is unsigned long long if we don't want to have overflow on this addition we must bound our exponent a such that:

```
//    3*(10^a-1) <= 2^64 - 1, and a an positive integer
// => a <= floor( Log10((2^64 - 1)/3 + 1) )
// => a <= 18
```

So this has now fixed are maximum possible a=18 and thus the biggest possible `n_` represented with `unsigned long long` is  `10^18 -1 = 999,999,999,999,999,999`. With this basic set up lets now get to some actual code. For now I will use `std::vector` to hold the `big_num` we discussed, but this can change:

```
// Example code with unsigned long long
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
//
// FOR NOW BigNum WILL BE REPRESENTED
// BY std::vector. YOU CAN CHANGE THIS LATTER
// DEPENDING ON WHAT OPTIMIZATIONS YOU WANT
//
using BigNum = std::vector<unsigned long long>;

// suffix ULL garanties number be interpeted as unsigned long long
#define MAX_BASE_10 999999999999999999ULL

// random generate big number
void randomize_BigNum(BigNum &a){
  // assuming MyRandom() returns a random number
  // of type unsigned long long
  for(size_t i=1; i<a.size(); i++)
    a[i] = MyRandom()%(MAX_NUM_BASE_10+1); // cap the numbers
}

// wrapper functions
void add(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b, BigNum &c); // c = a + b
void add(const BigNum &a, BigNum &b);         // b = a + b

// actual work done here
void add_equal_size(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b, BigNum &c, size_t &N);
void add_equal_size(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b, size_t &N);
void blindly_add_one(BigNum &c);
// Missing cases
// void add_equal_size(BigNum &a, BigNum &b, BigNum &c, size_t &Na, size_t &Nb);
// void add_equal_size(BigNum &a, BigNum &b, size_t &Na, size_t &Nb);

int main(){
  size_t n=10;
  BigNum a(n), b(n), c(n);
  randomize_BigNum(a);
  randomize_BigNum(b);
  add(a,b,c);
  return;
}
```

The wrapper functions should look as follows. They will safe guard against incorrect size of array calls:

```
// To do: add support for when size of a,b,c not equal

// c = a + b
void add(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b, BigNum &c){

  c.resize(std::max(a.size(),b.size()));

  if(a.size()==b.size())
    add_equal_size(a,b,c,a.size());
  else
    // To do: add_unequal_size(a,b,c,a.size(),b.size());

  return;
};
// b = a + b
void add(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b){

  if(a.size()==b.size())
    add_equal_size(a,b,a.size());
  else{
    b.resize(a.size());
    // To do: add_unequal_size(a,b,a.size());
  }

  return;
};
```

The main grunt of the work will be done here (which you can call directly and skip a function call, if you know what you are doing):

```
// If a,b,c same size array
// c = a + b
void add_equal_size(const BigNum &a, const BigNum &b, BigNum &c, const size_t &N){
  // start with sign of c is sign of a
  // Specific details follow on whether I need to flip the
  // sign or not
  c[0] = a[0];
  unsigned long long carry=0;

  // DISTINGUISH TWO GRAND CASES:
  //
  // a and b have the same sign
  // a and b have oposite sign
  // no need to check which has which sign (details follow)
  //
  if(a[0]==b[0]){// if a and b have the same sign
    //
    // This means that either +a+b or -a-b=-(a+b)
    // In both cases I just need to add two numbers a and b
    // and I already got the sign of the result c correct form the
    // start
    //
    for(size_t i=1; i<N;i++){
      c[i]  = (a[i] + b[i] + carry)%(MAX_BASE_10+1);
      carry = c[i]/(MAX_BASE_10+1);      
    }
    if(carry){// if carry>0 then I need to extend my array to fit the final carry
      c.resize(N+1);
      c[N]=carry;
    }
  }
  else{// if a and b have opposite sign
    //
    // If I have opposite sign then I am subtracting the
    // numbers. The following is inspired by how
    // you can subtract two numbers with bitwise operations.
    for(size_t i=1; i<N;i++){
      c[i]  = (a[i] + (MAX_BASE_10 - b[i]) + carry)%(MAX_BASE_10+1);
      carry = c[i]/(MAX_BASE_10+1);      
    }
    if(carry){ // I carried? then I got the sign right from the start
      // just add 1 and I am done
      blindly_add_one(c);
    }
    else{ // I didn't carry? then I got the sign wrong from the start
      // flip the sign
      c[0] ^= 1ULL;
      // and take the compliment
      for(size_t i=1; i;<N;i++)
    c[i] = MAX_BASE_10 - c[i];
    }
  }
  return;
};
```

A few details about the `// if a and b have opposite sign` case follow:
Lets work in base 10. Lets say we are subtracting `a - b` Lets convert this to an addition. Define the following operation:

Lets name the base 10 digits of a number `di`. Then any number is `n = d1 + 10*d2 + 10*10*d3...` The compliment of a digit will now be defined as:

```
     `compliment(d1) = 9-d1`
```

Then the compliment of a number `n` is:

```
   compliment(n) =         compliment(d1)
                   +    10*compliment(d2)
                   + 10*10*compliment(d3)
                   ...
```

Consider two case, `a>b` and `a<b`:

EXAMPLE OF `a>b`: lest say `a=830` and `b=126`. Do the following `830 - 126 -> 830 + compliment(126) = 830 + 873 = 1703` ok so if `a>b`, I drop the 1, and add 1 the result is 704!

EXAMPLE OF `a<b`: lest say `a=126` and `b=830`. Do the following `126 - 830 -> 126 + compliment(830) = 126 + 169 = 295` ...? Well what if I compliment it? `compliment(295) = 704` !!! so if `a<b` I already have the result... with opposite sign.

Going to our case, since each number in the array is bounded by MAX_BASE_10 the compliment of our numbers is

`compliment(n) = MAX_BASE_10 - n`

So using this compliment to convert subtraction to addition
I only need to pay attention to if I carried an extra 1 at
the end of the addition (the `a>b` case). The algorithm now is

- FOR EACH ARRAY subtraction (ith iteration):
- na_i - nb_i + carry(i-1)
- convert          -> na_i + compliment(nb_i) + carry(i-1)
- bound the result -> (na_i + compliment(nb_i) + carry(i-1))%MAX_BASE_10
- find the carry   -> (na_i + compliment(nb_i) + carry(i-1))/MAX_BASE_10
- keep on adding the array numbers...
- At the end of the array if I carried, forget the carry
  and add 1. Else take the compliment of the result

This "and add one" is done by yet another function:

```
// Just add 1, no matter the sign of c
void blindly_add_one(BigNum &c){
  unsigned long long carry=1;
  for(size_t i=1; i<N;i++){
    c[i]  = carry%(MAX_BASE_10+1);
    carry = c[i]/(MAX_BASE_10+1);
  }
  if(carry){ // if carry>0 then I need to extend my basis to fit the number
    c.resize(N+1);
    c[N]=carry;
  }
};
```

Good up to here. Specifically in this code don't forget that at the start of the function we set the sign of `c` to the sign of `a`. So if I carry at the end, that means I had `|a|>|b|` and I did either `+a-b>0` or `-a+b=-(a-b)<0`. In either case setting the results `c` sign to `a` sign was correct. If I don't carry I had `|a|<|b|` with either `+a-b<0` or `-a+b=-(a-b)>0`. In either case setting the results `c` sign to `a` sign was INCORRECT so I need to flip the sign if I don't carry.

The following functions opperates the same way as the above one, only rather than do `c = a + b` it dose `b = a + b`

```
// same logic as above, only b = a + b
void add_equal_size(BigNum &a, BigNum &b, size_t &N){

  unsigned long long carry=0;
  if(a[0]==b[0]){// if a and b have the same sign
    for(size_t i=1; i<N;i++){
      b[i]  = (a[i] + b[i] + carry)%(MAX_BASE_10+1);
      carry = b[i]/(MAX_BASE_10+1);      
    }
    if(carry){// if carry>0 then I need to extend my basis to fit the number
      b.resize(N+1);
      b[N]=carry;
    }
  }
  else{ // if a and b have oposite sign
    b[0] = a[0];
    for(size_t i=1; i<N;i++){
      b[i]  = (a[i] + (MAX_BASE_10 - b[i]) + carry)%(MAX_BASE_10+1);
      carry = b[i]/(MAX_BASE_10+1);      
    }
    if(carry){
      add_one(b);
    }
    else{
      b[0] ^= 1ULL;
      for(size_t i=1; i;<N;i++)
    b[i] = MAX_BASE_10 - b[i];
    }
  }
  return;
};
```

And that is a basic set up on how you could use unsigned numbers in arrays to represent very large integers.

**WHERE TO GO FROM HERE**

Their are many thing to do from here on out to optimise the code, I will mention a few I could think of:

-Try and replace addition of arrays with possible BLAS calls

-Make sure you are taking advantage of vectorization. Depending on how you write your loops you may or may not be generating vectorized code. If your arrays become big you may benefit from this.

-In the spirit of the above make sure you have properly aligned arrays in memory to actually take advantage of vectorization. From my understanding `std::vector` dose not guaranty alignment. Neither dose a blind `malloc`. I think boost libraries have a vector version where you can declare a fixed alignment in which case you can ask for a 64bit aligned array for your `unsigned long long` array. Another option is to have your own class that manages a raw pointer and dose aligned allocations with a custom alocator. Borrowing `aligned_malloc` and `aligned_free` from https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/22/generating-aligned-memory/ you could have a class like this to replace std::vector:

```
// aligned_malloc and aligned_free from:
// https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/22/generating-aligned-memory/

// wrapping in absolutly minimal class to handle
// memory allocation and freeing 
class BigNum{
private:
  unsigned long long *ptr;
  size_t size;
public:  
  BigNum() : ptr(nullptr)
       , size(0)
  {};  

  BigNum(const size_t &N) : ptr(nullptr)
              , size(N)
  {
    resize(N);
  }  
  // Defining destructor this will now delete copy and move constructor and assignment. Make your own if you need them
  ~BigNum(){
    aligned_free(ptr);
  }  

  // Access an object in aligned storage
  const unsigned long long& operator[](std::size_t pos) const{
    return *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long long*>(&ptr[pos]);
  }
  // return my size
  void size(){    
    return size;
  }
  // resize memory allocation
  void resize(const size_t &N){
    size = N;
    if(N){
      void* temp = aligned_malloc(ptr,N+1); // N+1, always keep first entry for the sign of BigNum 
      if(temp!=nullptr)
    ptr = static_cast<unsigned long long>(temp);
      else
    throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    else{
      aligned_free(ptr);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: unsigned long long is 64 bits wide. how do you come to 128 bits ?

Comment: I was thinking as an example to represent 100 bits, and if my  array is made of  `unsigned long long` (64 bits,) I need three numbers in the array, one for the sing, and two more that will give me a combined 128 bit. And then one needs to deal with the carry overs of course between these two entries.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but as you can see, I generate N random values in base 10, and save them into an array. If I just generate a random unsigned long long, the result will be completely different, right? (MyRandom() is a pseudo random function, so that in every execution the results will remain the same). Or maybe you were talking about, once all N values are generated, associate them to a i.e. long long variable? Is that even possible?

Comment: To be honest given the base 10 constraint, dealing with base 2 (which is what I was thinking in my original post) may not be the way to go.  Every `unsigned long long (lets shorten this to ull)` would have to represent a base 10 number, so you would need to cap the max allowed `ull` number of the array entries, probably with a `%` operation `(ull%(max_allowed+1))`, and now bit operations would not be a trivial task as you would be tracking base 10 operations with base 2 representation. This would need a bit of thinking to flesh out for base 10.

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort done for this question. I will apply these changes in my code, also achieving vectorization is my main goal for this task. Thank you for the advice and your time!