# Is it possible to create custom-width integers in C?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

The C standard and C compilers come with fixed width integer types, such as `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, etc.

Is there a way of defining a 128-bit integer in C that would be useable in code using the same semantics as the existing fixed-width integers?

Comment: No operator overloads to custom types in C so not really.  You will need to call add(), subtract(), etc. functions instead.

Comment: If you want something that behaves like a built-in type but is actually a special type with custom behaviors, you would be better off using a C++ object. You could easily make a C++ object with standard integer-like semantics that worked in 128-bit.

Comment: I'm working on a pure-C code base.

Comment: You might want to check whether you have support for `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` built into your GCC compiler.  See [How to print `uint128_t` number using GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need something like GMP:

- http://gmplib.org/

You won't get the "exact" semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're programming a 64-bit machine, you could define a `uint128_t` type as a `struct` of two `uint64_t`s and implement just the arithmetic operators you need by hand.  You'd have to manually handle carrying bits from the low 64 bits to the high or vice versa in the case of an operation that overflows in one or the other direction.  (For example, add 0xFFFFFFFF to 0x00000001.)  That would be much lighter-weight than using an entire library for arbitrary-size bignums like GMP.  It'd be a bit tricky to write but by no means impossible--it's pretty much how the built-in BASICs on 8-bit computers back in the day handled math with numbers larger than 255, for example.