# How to print __int128 in g++

Tags: c++, string, g++, int128

I'm working with `__int128`s in g++ and need to print them. I found this question: [How to print __int128 in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/how-to-print-int128-in-g) but it is 6 years old: is there a better way to do it in modern c++?

Comment: It seems that C++ still does not provide support for it. So that answer still stands.

Comment: I mean, the algorithms they used, is there a nicer way of doing them now?

Comment: There are two answers from last year, and two answers from _this_ year...

Comment: The idea is to convert the value to a string, you can have a more or less elegant way to do it but that's basically it.

Comment: "*is there a nicer way*" I don't think so, it's still "divide by 10 and repeat"...

Comment: For what it's worth, here's Google's answer: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/numeric/int128.cc#L212