# Why is the compiler unable to match the types automatically on `size_t` variables in a ranged base for loop?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, std-ranges, c++23

I stumbled upon a problem with ambiguous overload for `operator<<` when using `std::views::enumerate` with `size_t` range.
More specifically using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
namespace rv = std::ranges::views;

int main()
{
    for (const auto& [idx, value] : rv::iota(0zu, 5zu) | rv::enumerate)
        std::cout << idx << '\n';
}
```

and compiling with `gcc 13.1.1` on linux using: `g++ --std=c++23 main.cpp`.
I get the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:19: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘std::tuple_element<0, const std::tuple<__int128, long unsigned int> >::type’ {aka ‘const __int128’})
   11 |         std::cout << idx << '\n';
      |         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~
      |              |       |
      |              |       std::tuple_element<0, const std::tuple<__int128, long unsigned int> >::type {aka const __int128}
      |              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

and then a bunch of candidates for the `<<` operator.

This can be remediated by casting `idx` (e.g., using `std::cout << (size_t)idx`) but it seems unnecessary tedious.
The problem seems to only occur when using `long` variables as start and end for the range.
For instance if we use `rv::iota(begin, end)` with either `int begin{0}, end{5}` (whether signed or unsigned) the problem disappears.

Is this a simple bug at the compiler level or is there something deeper preventing it from matching the correct type?

Comment: Related [Overload of std::ostream for __int128_t ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053030/overload-of-stdostream-for-int128-t-ambiguous-when-called-from-a-namespace). Also refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find related SO posts.

Comment: See also dupe1 [Output 128 bit integer using stream operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735391/output-128-bit-integer-using-stream-operator)

Comment: @Jason The duplicate is not a good one, because the exact type of `idx` is an implementation detail of `rv::iota` that shouldn't be relevant to whether or not OP's code is valid.

Comment: @user17732522 Dupe2 [How to print __int128 in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/how-to-print-int128-in-g)

Comment: @user17732522 There was no need to reopen the post as there are also many other duplicates that can be added to the list. For example [cout cannot print __int128 - MinGW-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112361/cout-cannot-print-int128-mingw-w64) is dupe3.

Comment: @Jason The question here is about whether or when it is guaranteed that the result of `rv::iota(0zu, 5zu) | rv::enumerate` can be printed with `<<` and if it isn't how it can be printed. `__in128` appears nowhere in this and is an implementation-detail. The user should not need to know or rely on the exact type.

Comment: @user17732522 The duplicates can be used to solve the error. If yes, then the targets are applicable as duplicates.

Comment: @Jason No, with the solutions given in these answers, OP's code would still have unspecified behavior because the actual type of `idx` is unspecified.

Comment: @user17732522 I see.

Comment: The `iota_view::iterator` is supposed to choose a `difference_type` that is wider than the type iterated over. [IOTA-DIFF-T(W)](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota#view-1) So not really a compiler bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `idx` is the `difference_type` of the `iota` view.

You are using the type `std::size_t` for the arguments to `iota`. Probably `std::size_t` has 64 bit width on your system and that is probably also the maximum width of any integer type on your system.

The problem now is that `difference_type` for the `iota` view cannot also be a 64 bit width type, since such a type wouldn't be able hold the difference between any two items in the range.

Therefore `iota` is specified to have a `difference_type` that has larger width than the width of the element type. If a signed integer type with that property exists, then `difference_type` will be a signed integer type. If such an integer doesn't exits, then `difference_type` will be a signed-integer-like type with sufficient width, i.e. a type that behaves in certain important ways like a signed integer type, but isn't one.

It could be e.g. a class type with properly overloaded operators or, as you are seeing, some implementation-specific type that is not considered an integer type, but has similar behavior. (Actually, whether GCC considers `__int128` an extended integer type or not depends on whether you use `-std=gnu++23` or `-std=c++23`.)

For a list of properties these types need to satisfy see [[iterator.concept.winc]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.winc).

However, `std::ostream::operator<<` is overloaded only for the *standard integer types*. `idx`'s type therefore doesn't have an exactly matching overload if it is only a signed-integer-like type.

You get the ambiguity error because the concrete type the implementation chose for `idx`, i.e. `__in128_t`, is implicitly convertible to all of the standard signed integer types with same conversion rank. (That would also be the case if `__int128_t` was considered an (extended) signed integer type.) However, this is an implementation detail. It isn't even guaranteed that the signed-intger-like type is implicitly convertible to any of the integer types (because they all have smaller width).

The explicit conversion with e.g. `static_cast` or a C-style cast is guaranteed to work to any integer type, but risks narrowing the result.

So there is no compiler bug here. This is the allowed behavior and you can't rely on being able to print `idx` with `operator<<` directly.

If you intent `iota` to only consider a range of `0` to `5`, the easiest solution would be to not use type `std::size_t`, but a smaller type of sufficient size instead, e.g. `rv::iota(0, 5)` if you know that `int` is 32 bit and you are on a 64 bit system.

If you do not intent to risk narrowing and you don't want to rely on knowing that there is a standard integer type with larger width on your system, then you'll have to convert the value of `idx` to a decimal string representation yourself. The usual arithmetic operators are guaranteed to work on the signed-integer-like type as expected, so that this is possible. But I don't think there is currently any standard library function that converts any signed-integer-like type to a decimal string representation.

Comment: Ok I see, it actually makes a lot of sense. I will have to think about how to handle it properly. My example is a heavy simplification of the situation. In my case the range depends on some Matrix sizes (hence the use of `std::size_t`) and it happens that the matrix accessors are not overloaded for this `__int128` type. But knowing where the problem lies should help, thanks :)