# cout cannot print __int128 - MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw-w64, int128

Previously I noticed that GCC has built-in support for 128-bit integer. now I'm trying it under MinGW but there are two problems with that:

1. I can't print it using `cout`.
2. I can't convert it to `string` neither by `string`'s constructor nor by functions like `to_string()`.

---

here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    __int128 a = 12;
    cout << a;
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and '__int128')
```

---

My guess is to overload `<<` operator for cout... but I don't know how?!

Also why cout doesn't have support for `__int128` when this is a built-in type?!

Comment: std::cout is part of the C++ Standard.  __int128 is not part of the C++ Standard.  It is a GCC extension (other compilers don't offer it)  If the standard doesn't have a 128 bit integer then you have to use GCC extensions to print it (they have one for printf) or make your own.  Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/how-to-print-int128-in-g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thanks it helped!