# How to output number in the range 64 bits to 128 bits ( like 2^64, 3^64, 4^64 etc)?

Tags: c, 64-bit, 128-bit

When i was coding i got a problem like: i need to output number which is 2^64 (also 3^64 and others). I have tried unsigned long long int, but it's still not enough (it contains 2^64-1). If anyone know how i can output numbers from 64bits to 128bits, just let me know (btw this task i'm trying to do on C).

Comment: That could be an XY-problem. Do you have a problem statement and your proposed solution?

Comment: c++ has `__int128` but for c you might have to write your own custom logic

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh `__int128` is a gcc extension and works in c or c++

Comment: 4^64 is outside 128-bit integer range.  `2^64, 4^64` are  available as `double`. What is the real problem?

Comment: @AlanBirtles didn't knew it works on c as well. But it doesn't has output operator so you might to define it yourself. something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/how-to-print-int128-in-g

Comment: A list of arbitrary precision libraries can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Comment: 2^64=10000...(64 0s) in binary. From there it's just a matter of converting to decimal while storing it as a string. Same for 3^64, 4^64 etc, but instead of binary use base 3, base 4 etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, compile this program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void)
{
    return (int128_t) 0;
}
```

If the compiler prints an error message about the identifier `int128_t`, then your compiler probably does not support integers wider than 64 bits, regardless of what the type name is.

In that case, you have at least three choices:

- If you do not need exact results, you can use `double` or `long double` floating-point, as in `printf("%g\n", pow(2, 64));`.
- You can write your own code to implement 128-bit arithmetic from smaller types. For short, simple programs, you can use the same techniques taught in elementary school for multiplying and adding numbers digit by digit, just using a type like `uint32_t` as a “digit” instead of a single decimal digit. Or you can implement them using single decimal digits, if you prefer. (For example, two `uint32_t` numbers can be converted to `uint64_t` and multiplied to make a 64-bit product which you then split into one `uint32_t` digit to be kept in the current position and one `uint32_t` digit to be carried to the next position.)
- Use an arbitrary-precision library, such as the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org). This will require downloading and configuring additional software.