# Output 128 bit integer using stream operator

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20, int128

I'm using GCC's 128 bit integer:

```
__extension__ using uint128_t = unsigned __int128;
uint128_t a = 545;
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

However, if I try to output using the stream operator I get the compiler error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘uint128_t’ {aka ‘__int128 unsigned’})
```

Is there a way to allow this?

Linux, GCC version 11.1, x86-64

Comment: Looks like you're doomed to writing `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, uint128_t val)`

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to print __int128 in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25114597/995714), but it doesn't target C++20 like this

Answer (score 3):

libstdc++ does not have an `ostream` overload for `__int128`. However, you can use C++20 `<format>` library, which supports `__int128` formatting in both libstdc++ and libc++.

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  __extension__ using uint128_t = unsigned __int128;
  uint128_t a = 545;
  std::cout << std::format("{}\n", a);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zvndKKed5)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to overload the `<<` operator yourself because `std::ostream` doesn't have an overload for that type as it is from an external lib. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-stream-insertion-operators-c/) could help.

Comment: "from an external lib" isn't the problem; lots of external libraries define appropriate operator overloads for I/O. The problem is that **this** lib doesn't.

Comment: @PeteBecker correct, that's why operator overloads should be checked among other things when working with external libs.