# which is the biggest datatype in c language to store large values?

Tags: c

what is the largest datatype in c in which I can store a large values like 10^17 etc? and also tell how to take user input,store,print  them in this particular case.

Comment: Use `unsigned long long int`. It can store up to `2^64 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

A particular implemention might optionally support implementation-defined *extended integer types* (N1570 `6.2.5` *Types*):

> 4) There may also be implementation-defined *extended signed integer
>   types*.<sup>38)</sup> The standard and extended signed integer types
>   are collectively called *signed integer types*.<sup>39</sup>)
>
> 6) The unsigned integer types that correspond to the extended signed
>   integer types are the extended unsigned integer types. The standard
>   and *extended unsigned integer types* are collectively called *unsigned
>   integer types*<sup>.40)</sup>

The motivitation is likely to allow 128-bit wide integers, but it seems to be no interest of it. It's more likely that particular implementation supports such integers via extension such as [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) in gcc.

However, if your requirement is up to 10<sup>17</sup>, then you will be fine with the standard unsigned integer type such as `unsigned long long int`. It guaranteed to be at least 64-bits wide, thus possible range is at least [0, 2<sup>64</sup>-1], that is slightly more than 18 * 10<sup>18</sup>.

Note that `long long` types were introduced in C99, but it's likely that even older C89 compiler supports them through extension. Check you compiler's documentation for any details.

Both `printf()` and `scanf()` expects prefix `ll` in format specifier. For instance:

```
unsigned long long n = ULLONG_MAX;
printf("lld", n);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegorz.

Comment: I just found this on stack overflow while i was searching for how to scanf an __int128. As your answer refers it, do you know how to scanf it? I am trying to store numbers 30 digits long

Comment: @TestitemQlstudop: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11658831/586873) answer. Long story short: you need to handle it by itself, or just use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library, that provides convenience functions like `gmp_scanf`.