# Convert int to binary string of certain size

Tags: c, binary

I'm struggling to adapt to C after programming in Java for some time and I need help. What I'm looking for is a method that takes following input:

1. Integer `n`, the one to be converted to binary string (character array).
2. Integer `length`, which defines the length of the string (positions from the left not filled with the binary numbers are going to be set to default 0).

   ```
   //Here's some quick code in Java to get a better understanding of what I'm looking for:

   public static String convertToBinary(int length, int n) {
     return String.format("%1$" + bit + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0');
   }

   System.out.println(convertToBinary(8,1));

   // OUTPUT:

   00000001 (not just 1 or 01)
   ```

Any hints on what the equivalent of this would be in C? Also, could you provide me with an example of how the resulting binary string should be returned?

*(not a duplicate, since what I'm looking for is '00000001', not simply '1')*

Comment: Please may I quote you for "after programming in Java for some time [...] I need help"?

Comment: "Not a duplicate" - perhaps 2 duplicates then, one for each question.

Comment: What if the number takes up more than `n` digits? Should it truncate or grow?

Comment: FYI, this does not look like C.  More like C# honestly.

Comment: The OP said it's Java.

Comment: Though not meant  for a learner, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34292060/2410359) may be useful to convert an `int` to a binary (or any base) string representation.

Comment: @KerrekSB Let's assume that the number won't take more than n digits. And quote me anywhere you want if you wish. xD

Comment: You have to write a binary formatter yourself. For hex you could use printf; hex is usually just as good (four bits per digits)... To write it yourself, I'd use a lookup table.

Comment: @SteveSummit, the OP is looking for the binary representation, not just leading zeros, so `%09d` won't help much.

Comment: @Ray Thanks, my mistake, comment deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C standard library does not contain an equivalent function to `Integer.toBinaryString()`.  The good news is, writing such a function won't be too complicated, and if you're in the process of learning C, this problem is fairly ideal for learning how to use the *bitwise operators*.

You'll want to consult an existing tutorial or manual for all the details, but here are a few examples of the sort of things that would be useful for this or similar tasks.  All numbers are unsigned integers in these examples.

`n >> m` shifts all bits in `n` right by `m` steps, and fills in zeros on the left side.  So if `n = 13 (1101 in binary)`, `n >> 1` would be `6 (i.e. 110)`, and `n >> 2` would be `3 (i.e. 11)`.

`n << m` does the same thing, but shifting left.  `3 << 2 == 12`.  This is equivalent to multiplying `n` by 2 to the power of m.  (If it isn't obvious why that is, you'll want to think about how binary numbers are represented for awhile until you understand it clearly; it'll make things easier if you have an intuitive understanding of that property.)

`n & m` evaluates to a number such that each bit of the result is 1 if and only if it's 1 in *both* n and m.  e.g. `12 & 5 == 4`, (1100, 0101, and 0100 being the respective representations of 12, 5, and 4).

So putting those together, `n & (1 << i)` will be nonzero if and only if bit i is set: `1` obviously only has a single bit set, `1 << i` moves it to the appropriate position, and `n & (1 << i)` checks if that position also has a 1 bit for `n`. (keeping in mind that the rightmost/least significant bit is bit *0*, not bit 1.)  So using that, it's a simple matter of checking each bit individually to see if it's 1 or 0, and you have your binary conversion function.

Answer (score -1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *convertToBinary(int length, int n) {
    unsigned num = (unsigned)n;
    int n_bit = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(num);
    if(length > n_bit){
        fprintf(stderr, "specified length  greater than maximum length.\n");
        length = n_bit;//or expand size?
    }

    char *bin = malloc(n_bit + 1);//static char bin[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(num)+1]; If you change, memmove(-->return p;), free is not necessary.
    memset(bin, '0', n_bit);
    bin[n_bit] = 0;

    char *p = bin + n_bit;
    do {
        *--p = "01"[num & 1];
        num >>= 1;
    }while(num);

    int bits = bin + n_bit - p;
    if(bits < length){
        p -= length - bits;
        return memmove(bin, p, length + 1);
    } else if(bits > length){
        fprintf(stderr, "Specified length is not enough.(%s but length is %d)\n", p, length);
        return memmove(bin, p, bits+1);//or cut off
/*
        free(bin);
        return ""; or return NULL;
*/
    }// else if(bits == length)
    return bin;
}

int main(void){
    char *sbin = convertToBinary(8, 1);
    puts(sbin);
    free(sbin);

    return 0;
}
```