# Why do I need to type cast when initializing a user-defined structure using pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, compound-literals

I have this structure definition:

```
typedef struct node_bst
{
  int data;
  struct node_bst *lchild;
  struct node_bst *rchild;
  struct node_bst *parent;
} node_bst;
```

I tried to create a pointer to the structure using this:

```
node_bst *root;
```

and allocated memory to it like this:

```
root= malloc(sizeof(node_bst));
```

Now, in order to initialize the data items in it I was tried this statement (taking a cue from the usual initialization of structure variables):

```
*root= {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

But the compiler threw off an error

> error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

I looked it up and found that I need to typecast it like this:

```
*root= (node_bst) {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Now it works fine but my question is, why do i need to do this?

I expected that the compiler would already know that root is a pointer to node_bst type structure variable. So why the need to typecast the rvalue?

Another strange thing:

```
int *a= malloc(sizeof(int));
*a= 4;
```

This works just fine.

Comment: Nothing to do with pointers - try `node_bst root; root = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};`.

Comment: @Oliver I am not trying to create a normal variable. I need a pointer to node_bst structure that stores the address of a piece of heap memory.

Comment: My point is that this behaviour is not specific to pointers.

Comment: In case of `*a = 4;`, you don't need a "cast" since the constant of type integer is just a number.

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal key point being - `(node_bst) {0, NULL, NULL, NULL}` is a single entity and not a cast followed by a struct.

Comment: That's a compound literal and you better make it `const`.

Comment: @Ajay @Oliver what is this `(node_bst)` anyways why do i need it? I mean `node_bst root= {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};`  works as i expected. Why?

Comment: In this context `(node_bst)` by itself is nothing. It is the `(node_bst)` along with the `{ ... }` that makes up a compound literal.

Comment: **Keep that in mind**: The compiler knows for the assignment operator. But not for the right side operand of the assignment which is the relevant issue. That applies to **all** operators and all types.

Comment: @chux I was not aware you could take the address of a compound literal.  Good to know!

Comment: @dbush but the lifetime of the literal is only local. So one shouldn't return the address of a compound literal up the call stack.

Comment: @dbush Same for _string literal_.  Here is [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34292061/2410359) that takes advantage of the addressability of a _compound literal_ and the ability to assign its contents

Comment: @Olaf what exactly do you want to make `const`?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The compound literal, of course (didn't I say that already?). It is not used for anything than initialisation. Might make no difference for a good compiler, but it is (a) more expressive and (b) "might be" is not a good thing to rely on.

Comment: @Olaf If you are referring to the "might be" I wrote on my last comment on VladFromMoscow's answer I said that because it is upto the compiler. It might or might not occupy space. It also depends on what you do with the compound literal. If you just use for initialization most compilers just assign the corresponding fields. If you take address of the compound literal my compiler puts it on the stack. So it can depend on the code.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: No, I refered to the sentence before in my comment. Lifetime is not the only thing. Problem is a bad compiler could do two copy operations: initialiser to literal and literal to `*root`. Note that compound literals are **not** constants! In fact even `static const` does not make a constant, but even not-so-good compilers should handle it that way. **and** it will help detect problems if e.g. the `*` on the lhs of the assignment is forgotten. Always head for safe code and support your compiler.

Comment: @Olaf that makes sense. Agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in use here is not a typecast but a **compound literal**.  These are defined in section 6.5.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* A  postfix  expression  that  consists  of  a  parenthesized  type  name  followed  by  a  brace-enclosed  list  of  initializers  is  a
>   *compound  literal*.  It provides  an  unnamed  object  whose value is given by the initializer list.

A compound literal is necessary when assigning to a `struct` as a whole.

You don't need this syntax in this case:

```
int *a= malloc(sizeof(int));
*a= 4;
```

Since `*a` has type `int` and `4` is a simple integer constant that can be assigned directly to `*a`.

Note also that the fact that a pointer is involved is irrelevant.  You would need to do the same in this case:

```
node_bst root;
root= (node_bst){0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

This is different from:

```
node_bst root = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

The former case is an *assignment*, while the latter is an *initialization*.  An initialization can only be done at the time a variable is defined (even outside of a function), while an assignment can be done at any time.

The syntax for initialization (see section 6.7.9 of the standard) allows for just the brace-enclosed list of values, while a compound literal is needed for an assignment.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can still use a compound literal in an initialization, and a compound literal has a lifetime of the current scope whose address you can take.

Here's an interesting example of this:

```
char *str = (char[]){ "My string" };
str[3] = 'S';
```

Here, the compound literal is being modified, which is allowed.  But if you do this:

```
char *str = "My string";
str[3] = 'S';
```

You'll instead be attempting to modify a string literal and will most likely get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer for why does `node_bst root= {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};` work?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Edited.  @NityeshAgarwal I've edited with details on initialization vs. assignment.

Comment: The other point to make clear is that a compound literal is not limited to use in assignment, it can be used both during assignment and initialization (e.g. `char *str = (char[]){  "My string" };`)

Comment: why does an initialization not need a compound literal?

Comment: If you are initializing the exact same declared type, there is no need for a compound literal during initialization, the compiler already knows the correct type...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the example you showed, is it similar to `char xyz[] = "My string"; char *str = xyz;` ?

Comment: It is somewhat similar. Generally `char *str = "stuff";` initializes a *string literal* in *read-only memory*. Using the *compound literal* changes `str` to a *pointer-to-array-of-chars* -- which you can modify freely. `:)`

Comment: @dbush. Exactly, that is why I first assigned the string to a char[] and then to *str. This would make *str mutable right?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Correct.  `str` is pointing to a non-const character array, not a string literal, so it can be modified.

Comment: @David Is what's the difference between an array of characters (like the one used in @Ajay 's example), a compound string literal and a normal string literal? By normal string literal i mean the literal in statements like `char *str= "My string";` . I know that a normal string literal is placed in the constant memory block.

Comment: An array of characters (e.g. `char str[] = "My string";`) is a traditionally *array* where all characters (elements of the array) are freely modifiable with storage generally created in the `.data` section. A *string literal* is created by creating a pointer to a string (e.g. `char *str = "My string";`) where the contents of `str` cannot be modified as storage is created within the `.rodata` section (read-only data). A *compound literal* allows you to initialize what would normally be a *string literal* as a *character array* in the case of the example I gave. It is a good learning example.

Answer (score 10):

There is no casting.

In this statement

```
*root = (node_bst) {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

there is used the so-called compound literal `(node_bst) {0, NULL, NULL, NULL}` that corresponds to an object of the type `node_bst` and this object is assigned to the object `*root`.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.5 Compound literals)

> 3 A postﬁx expression that consists of a parenthesized type name
>   followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers is a compound
>   literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the
>   initializer list.

Another approach is just to assign each data member of the dynamically allocated object. For example

```
root->data   = 0;
root->lchil  = NULL;
root->rchil  = NULL;
root->parent = NULL;
```

As for this statement

```
*root= {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

then it is invalid from the C point of view. You may use the braced initialization only in a declaration.

The statement would be valid if you compile the program as a C++ program.

Comment: One small difference between using compound literal and assigning each value individually is that compound literals do have their own memory. As a result you can take address of the compounf literal. (I am unsure about their lifetime).

Comment: why does `node_bst root= {0, NULL, NULL, NULL};` work?

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal because `T var = ... ;` and `T var; var = ...;` are different. One if initialization and other is declaration and then assignment. Both have different semantics

Comment: @Ajay "compount literals have their own memory" does it mean that when i write the code using compound literals, i am using twice the memory? Once during `malloc(sizeof(node_bst))` and then again when i use compound literal.

Comment: Got to love it! Straight forward, succinct and no wasted words `:)`

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal I just checked, compound literals have local scope (ie they are allocated on the stack). So yes twice the memory *might* be used. But you don't have to worry about freeing it.