# Largest range of datatype in C++

Tags: c++

I wanted a datatype which can hold as large as 10^21. After searching enough, I got unsigned long long as holding somewhere around 18*10^18 which is still not enough. What shall I do ?

Comment: Depends on your application. Is integer-level precision required?

Comment: use `std::numeric_limits`

Comment: Aaah. Long and double will not work. So, I need something else.

Comment: Well, what was that ? Went straight above my head !!

Comment: @Jacob what about to implement you own class to keep it? Or you want to find an standart solution?

Comment: Both ways will work but the standard one will be handy and simpler, I hope !

Comment: Try this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html

Boost has types up to 1024 bit size.

Comment: Well, there what does "unsigned i" mean in the loop at the end of the page ?

Comment: There's always [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g++`, `clang++`, and most platforms support `__uint128` and `__int128`, which hold 128 bits. You can use them like normal integers, but they tend to be a bit [less compatible with the standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc).

This can hold numbers up to `2^128 ~ 10^38`

You could alternatively use `double` or `float`, but you will lose precision.

Or you could use a [BigInt library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/), which allows arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: Thanks ,but how shall I use these in my program ?

Comment: @Jacob Like normal integers. But bigger. Note that `uint` means `unsigned int`.

Comment: Is it applicable for some specific processors ?

Comment: I hope that I will have to just replace "int" with "_uint128" OR something else needs to be added ?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, this should be fine. Actually after a bit more research, your processor must have support for 128 bit long long. I think most modern processors do though, so you should be fine.

Comment: Is there a shorter sized int than this one if I want to be memory specific !!

Comment: Is there any difference between adding #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp> , then using int128_t  AND the way u provided (__unit128)  ??

Comment: @Jacob Unfortunately ints go in multiples of 2. But if you use a BigInt Library, it might allocate memory better (even though the way memory is usually expanded is in multiples of 2, so probably not).

Comment: @Jacob I didn't know about boost. That's good to know. I suppose it's similar but don't we all love built-in stuff?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170579/discussion-between-gill-bates-and-jacob).

Answer (score 0):

We used Magma for these sorts of numbers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system)
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/

Not sure if they have a C++ library but something to look into.  The numbers these things can hold were pretty impressive.