# Multiplying very large hex numbers and printing them in C

Tags: c, unsigned-long-long-int

I want to multiply 2 very big hex numbers and print them out like for example:

```
28B2D48D74212E4F x 6734B42C025D5CF7 = 1068547cd3052bbe5688de35695b1239
```

Since I expected it to be a very big number I used `unsigned long long int` type:

```
unsigned long long int x = 0x28B2D48D74212E4F;   
unsigned long long int y = 0x6734B42C025D5CF7;
```

and print the multiplication like this:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%llx\n",  x*y);
```

What I get is exactly the half of the expected result:

```
5688de35695b1239
```

Why does  it truncate it to exactly the half? Is there something bigger than `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Your `unsigned long long int` is obviously a 64bit number. Check again the `ULLONG_MAX`, you probably got it wrong.

Comment: *" tried to see if the output is bigger than ULLONG_MAX"* - how did you do that? The output is a lot larger than the max size of `unsigned long long` on any system I know of, you cannot compare against it, since it overflows on the arithmetic

Comment: Are you expecting `unsigned long long` to be 128 bits on your platform? Which platform would that be?

Comment: Some compilers offer a 128-bit `uintmax_t`;  or things like `__uint128`

Comment: @SteveFriedl I expect to get `1068547cd3052bbe5688de35695b1239` as my output

Comment: Ok, but what platform / compiler are you using?

Comment: @SteveFriedl sorry, gcc

Comment: Platform - linux, windows, armv7h, alpha? 32bit, 64bit? Gcc may have `__uint128` on your platform, you can print it as two 64-bit words.

Comment: @KamilCuk linux, 64 bit. How would I print it as two 64-bit words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you're looking for won't fit in a 64-bit `unsigned long long`, which is the normal size on a 64-bit platform; any excess during multiply is overflow and dropped.

Newer versions of GCC do support 128-bit integers *on 64-bit machines* with `__int128` (and `unsigned __int128`), and this works:

```
unsigned long long int x = 0x28B2D48D74212E4FULL;
unsigned long long int y = 0x6734B42C025D5CF7ULL;
unsigned __int128 xy = x * (unsigned __int128)y;
```

Note that you have to cast one of `x` or `y` to the wider type so the multiplication is done in 128 bits; otherwise that promotion to 128 is not done until after the (truncated) 64-bit multiply.

The problem is, as far as I can tell, `printf()` doesn't have a way to do this easily, so you're going to have to roll your own a bit.

Some reasonable discussion here: [how to print __uint128_t number using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc)

But this worked for me on:

> gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned long long int x = 0x28B2D48D74212E4F;
unsigned long long int y = 0x6734B42C025D5CF7;
unsigned __int128 xy = x * (unsigned __int128)y;

    printf("Result = %016llx%016llx\n",
        (unsigned long long)( xy >> 64),
        (unsigned long long)( xy & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL));

    return 0;
```

The casts inside the `printf` are important: otherwise the shifting/masking are done in 128-bit scalars, and those 128 bits pushed onto the stack, but then each `%llx` expects 64 bits.

Note that this is all entirely dependent on the underlying platform and is **not portable**; there's surely a way to use various #ifdefs and sizeofs to make it more general, but there's probably no super awesome way to make this work everywhere.

Comment: Note: `LL` in `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL` is OK, but not needed.  `U` is not _needed_ either here as a hex constant, but still good to use for _unsigned_ constants.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in fact the whole `&` operation is redundant, they could just put `(unsigned long long)xy`.  Which I would even say is an improvement as you can't miscount the F's

Comment: actually I take back my last comment, it's possible that `unsigned long long` is also 128-bit.  Maybe using `UINT64_MAX` as the mask would be smart; or using `uint64_t` in the first place