# (de)serialize struct containing __uint128_t in c++

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a vector of structs containing the __uint128_t datatype. Following is an attempt to write a simplified version, without utilizing sizeof(Test) to serialize:

```
typedef __uint128_t data_t;
//typedef uint64_t data_t;

struct Test {
data_t element;
int count;

Test()=default;

};

template<typename POD>
std::ostream& serialize(std::ostream& os, const POD& v)
{
  static_assert(std::is_trivial<POD>::value && std::is_standard_layout<POD>::value,
    "Can only serialize POD types with this function");

  printf("in POD, sizeof(POD): %lu\n", sizeof(v));
  os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v), sizeof(POD));
  return os;
}

template<typename POD>
std::istream& deserialize(std::istream& is, POD& v)
{
  static_assert(std::is_trivial<POD>::value && std::is_standard_layout<POD>::value,
    "Can only deserialize POD types with this function");

  is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v), sizeof(POD));
  return is;
}

int main()
{

 std::string tmp_buffer;
 std::stringstream oss;
 
 std::vector<Test>data_in(2);

 data_in[0].element=2345;
 data_in[0].count=4;

 data_in[1].element=5431;
 data_in[1].count=10;

 serialize(oss, data_in[0].element);
 serialize(oss, data_in[0].count);
 serialize(oss, data_in[1].element);
 serialize(oss, data_in[1].count);

 tmp_buffer = oss.str();
 printf("buffer len: %lu\n", tmp_buffer.size());

 Test k1;
 deserialize(oss, k1.element);
 deserialize(oss, k1.count);
 printf("data_out0: element: %llu, count: %d\n", k1.element, k1.count);

 Test k2;
 deserialize<data_t>(oss, k2.element);
 deserialize<int>(oss, k2.count);
 printf("data_out1: element: %llu, count: %d\n", k2.element, k2.count);

 assert(data_in[0].element == k1.element);
 assert(data_in[0].count == k1.count); /* passes ? */

 int c=k1.count;
 Test x = Test{k1.element, c};
 printf("c: %d, element: %llu, count: %d\n", c, x.element, x.count);

 return 0;

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
in POD, sizeof(POD): 16
in POD, sizeof(POD): 4
in POD, sizeof(POD): 16
in POD, sizeof(POD): 4
buffer len: 64
data_out0: element: 2345, count: 0
data_out1: element: 5431, count: 0
c: 4, element: 2345, count: 0
```

The value of count is printed as `0`, even though it passes the assert statement. Why am I seeing correct values for `element` and not for `count`?

If `data_t` is set as `uint64_t`, the output is correct for values of both `element` and `count`. Why am I seeing a discrepancy for the `__uint128_t` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assert passes because its condition is true. The problem is actually that you're trying to print `x.element` before `x.count`. `x.element` is an extended integer type, and [there is no support for printing extended integers in the C standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc) (extended integers don't exist in the C standard), so `printf` doesn't know how to handle the data you're giving it. There is no guarantee as to what `printf` will do in such a case; it's implementation-dependent. Not to mention, you're trying to print it with `%llu`, implying that it's an `unsigned long long`, but it isn't. An `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bytes of space; your extended integer type requires 128 bytes of space.

If you don't print `x.element`, then `x.count` will print just fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am glad to know that the problem was not in my approach to (de)serialize.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
printf("data_out1: element: %llu, count: %d\n", k2.element, k2.count);
```

try to print count only:

```
printf("data_out1: count: %d\n", k2.count);
```

It should print OK.

The problem is that `printf`'s `%llu` doesn't work with 128-bit value

Comment: Thank you Vlad!! That worked. I am glad that the original approach is sound.