# How to know if __uint128_t is defined

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, 128-bit

We can use the preprocessor to know if `unsigned long long` is defined:

```
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef ULLONG_MAX
typedef unsigned long t_mask; 
#else
typedef unsigned long long t_mask;
#endif
```

But how to know if `__uint128_t` is defined?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try the following. I do not know how reliable this is, but it might be the easiest way.

```
#ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__
    // do some fancy stuff here
#else
    // do some fallback stuff here
#endif
```

Comment: This is what the Linux kernel does, see include/linux/math64.h.

Answer (score 3):

find your cc1 in the /usr/libexec/gcc tree, then interrogate it:

```
$ strings /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/cc1 | grep uint128_t
__uint128_t            (or not)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [the `__uint128_t` type is a GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#_005f_005fint128), the proper thing to do is probably to check for some known-good version of GCC.

[See this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for information about the macros used to version-check the GCC compiler.

Comment: Clang is aware of it to support GCC code, so I would lean towards Sparky's solution

Comment: The gcc extension is `__int128` -- `__int128_t`/`__uint128_t` is an intel ICC extension later picked up by most other compilers.

Comment: `unsigned __int128` is only supported by gcc on 64-bit targets, so a version check is insufficient unless you know you're only ever compiling for x86-64, AArch64, MIPS64, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I have not yet dealt with __uint128_t, but based on existing pattern usage, I would expect the following.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef UINT128MAX
    #error "__uint128_t not defined"
#endif
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Compilers (e.g. x86-64 gcc8.2) don't define this in stdint.h or limits.h.