# NASM ctypes SIMD - how to access 128-bit array returned to ctypes?

Tags: pointers, nasm, ctypes

I have a NASM 64 dll called by ctypes.  The program multiplies two 64-bit integers and returns a 128-bit integer, so I am using xmm SIMD instructions.  It loops through 10,000 times and stores its results in a memory buffer created by malloc.

Here is the part of the NASM code where the SIMD calculations are performed:

```
cvtsi2sd xmm0,rax
mov rax,[pcalc_result_0]
cvtsi2sd xmm1,rax
PMULUDQ xmm0,xmm1

lea rdi,[rel s_ptr] ; Pointer
mov rbp,qword[rdi]
mov rcx,[s_ctr]
;movdqa [rbp + rcx],xmm0
movdqu [rbp + rcx],xmm0
add rcx,16
```

The movdqa instruction does not work (the program crashes, even though it's assembled with the align=16 directive).  The movdqu instruction does work, but when I return the array to ctypes, I need to convert the return pointer to 128-bits, but there is no 128-bit ctypes datatype.  Here's the relevant part of the ctypes code:

```
CallName.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]
CallName.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)

n0 = ctypes.cast(a[0],ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64))
n0_size = int(a[0+1] / 8)
x0 = n0[:n0_size]
```

where x0 is the returned array converted to a usable form, but not to 128 bits.

There is a post at [Handling 128-bit integers with ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631698/handling-128-bit-integers-with-ctypes) that deals with passing 128-bit arrays in but not out.

My questions are:

-- Should I use an instruction other than movdqa or movdqu?  Of the many SIMD instructions, these seem the most appropriate.

-- Python can handle integers up to any arbitrary size, but apparently ctypes can't.  Is there any way to use 128-bit integers from ctypes when there is no ctypes size larger than 64 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate byte arrays containing 16 bytes representing a 128-bit integer and convert to and from byte format.  This may not be aligned, so you should use `movdqu`.  I would use an input/output parameter instead of a return value, so Python can manage the memory:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> value = 0xaabbccddeeff
>>> int128 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(value.to_bytes(16,'little',signed=True))
>>> int128
<ctypes.c_char_Array_17 object at 0x000001ECCB1D41C8>
>>> int128.raw
b'\xff\xee\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

(NOTE: The buffer gets null-terminated, which is why it is 17 bytes)

Pass this writable buffer to your function, the function can write the result back to the same buffer.  On return use the following to convert back to a Python integer:

```
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(int128.raw[:16],'little',signed=True))
'0xaabbccddeeff'
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  Your example works for a single 16-byte number.  I created a string buffer of 800K bytes (for 50,000 16-byte integers), but on return your conversion string returns only a single integer, even if I increase the slice index.  For example:  return_array = int.from_bytes(int128.raw[:160],'little',signed=True) returns only a single integer, not 10 integers.  How can I convert the returned array to a Python integer array, not just the first value?  I did further research on .raw but it hasn't answered the question.

Comment: @RTC222 You'd have to walk the string 16 bytes at a time converting each one.  For example `.raw[0:16]` then `.raw[16:32]`, etc.  A one-liner to do it:  `arr = [int.from_bytes(int128.raw[n:n+16],'little',signed=True) for n in range(0,len(int128.raw),16)]`

Comment: That works, but it leads to a NASM-specific question.  I arbitrarily inserted the integer 1983452 in each of the 50,000 data slots, but it returns the integer 4701269677488209920.  I think this is because the 64-bit number is inserted at offset zero, but needs to be zero-extended. because it fills only the low quadword of the 16-bytes.  I think I need a SIMD instruction for that, so I'll investigate now.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: My last comment is not the answer -- a 64-bit value is in the lower quadword.  I'm still looking for the answer.