# Is there a 256-bit integer type?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, bigint, extended-precision

OS: Linux (Debian 10)

CC: GCC 8.3

CPU: i7-5775C

There is a `unsigned __int128`/`__int128` in GCC, but is there any way to have a `uint256_t`/`int256_t` in GCC?

I have read of a `__m256i` which seems to be from Intel.  Is there any header that I can include to get it?

Is it as usable as a hypothetic `unsigned __int256`?  I mean if you can assign from/to it, compare them, bitwise operations, etc.

What is its signed equivalent (if any)?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I achieved this:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
typedef __m256i uint256_t;
```

and compiled. If I can do some operations with it, I'll update it here.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Issues found:

```
uint256_t   m;
int         l = 5;

m = ~((uint256_t)1 << l);
```

ouput:

```
error: can’t convert a value of type ‘int’ to vector type ‘__vector(4) long long int’ which has different size
  m = ~((uint256_t)1 << l);
```

Comment: of course you can't just use `__m256i` as an integer type because it isn't an integer type but a vector, as mentioned in the error output. See [Is it possible to use SSE and SSE2 to make a 128-bit wide integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200698/995714), [Integer SIMD Instruction AVX in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24399754/995714), [practical BigNum AVX/SSE possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27923192/995714)

Comment: if you just want a 256-bit int type then there are a lot of duplicates [128/256-bit fixed size integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5242819/995714), [Representing 128-bit numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1188939/995714), [C++: How do I store a 256 bit number, and how do I convert it to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5344049/995714)...

Comment: @phuclv All those questions are C++.  I'll have a look at them to see if something is useful in C though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clang had [`_ExtInt` extended integers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types) that supports operations other than division, but SIMD isn't useful for that because of carry between elements<sup>1</sup>.  Other mainstream x86-64 compilers don't even have that; you need a library or something to define a custom type and use the same add-with-carry instructions clang will use.  (Or a less efficient emulation in pure C<sup>2</sup>).

**This has now been renamed `_BitInt(n)`, and will be part of ISO C23.  (`clang -std=gnu2x`)**.
As an extension, clang also accepts `_BitInt` in C++, regardless of revision, even with `-std=c++11` rather than `-std=gnu++11`.  Also in earlier C revisions, like `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11`.

---

```
typedef unsigned _BitInt(256) u256;
typedef /*signed*/ _BitInt(256) i256;

// works with clang 16
// but not GCC yet (as of April 2023)

int lt0(i256 a){
    return a < 0;  // just the sign bit in the top limb
}

// -march=broadwell allows mulx which clang uses, and adox/adcx which it doesn't
u256 mul256(u256 a, u256 b){
    return a*b;
}
```

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:14,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:14,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:14,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:14,startLineNumber:19),source:%27typedef+unsigned+_BitInt(256)+u256%3B%0Atypedef+/*signed*/+_BitInt(128)+i256%3B%0A%0Aint+lt0(i256+a)%7B%0A++++return+a+%3C+0%3B++//+just+the+sign+bit+in+the+top+limb%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+gt0(i256+a)%7B%0A++++return+a+%3E+(i256)0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+-march%3Dbroadwell+allows+mulx+which+clang+uses,+and+adox/adcx+which+clang+doesn!%27t.%0Au256+mul256(u256+a,+u256+b)%7B%0A++++return+a*b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23if+1%0Au256+div_n_by_small_constant(u256+a)%7B%0A++++return+a/10%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Au256+div_n_by_n(u256+a,+u256+b)%7B%0A++++return+a/b%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:29.756030701754383,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dgnu2x+-O3+-march%3Dskylake+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.6108826754386,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cgsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dgnu2x+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:36.63308662280702,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with clang `-std=gnu2x` - works even with `-m32`, where it's 8x 32-bit limbs instead of just 4x 64-bit.  **Multiply and divide expand inline to a large amount of code, not calling helper functions, so use carefully.**

- Clang 11 and 12 supported `_ExtInt(256)`, except for divide wider than 128.  Not `_BitInt`.
  `a<0` required explicit casts like `a < (i256)0`.
- Clang 13 added implicit conversion from `int` to `_ExtInt` types.  Still no divide support for integers wider than 128-bit.
- **Clang 14 and 15 support `_BitInt(n)`**, but only for sizes up to `_BitInt(128)`, so all supported sizes support division.
- **Clang 16 and later accept `unsigned _BitInt(256) bar;`, including mul and div** (but it's expanded inline, not a helper function, so code-size is large for those ops.)
- **GCC 12 and pre-13 trunk don't yet support `_BitInt` at all.**

---

#### SIMD 256-bit vectors aren't 256-bit scalar integers

`__m256i` is AVX2 SIMD 4x `uint64_t` (or a narrower element size like 8x `uint32_t`).  **It's not a 256-bit scalar integer type**, you can't use it for scalar operations, `__m256i var = 1` won't even compile.  There is no x86 *SIMD* support for integers wider than 64-bit, and the Intel intrinsic types like `__m128i` and `__m256i` are purely for SIMD.  You can do bitwise boolean ops with them.

GCC's `__int128` / `unsigned __int128` typically uses scalar `add/adc`, and/or scalar `mul` / `imul`, because AVX2 is generally not helpful for extended precision, unless you use [a partial-word storage format so you can defer carry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866973/can-long-integer-routines-benefit-from-sse).  (SIMD is helpful for stuff like bitwise AND/OR/XOR where element boundaries are irrelevant.)

---

**Footnote 1**: There actually is some scope for using SIMD for BigInteger types, but only with a specialized format.  And more importantly, you have to manually choose when to re-normalize (propagate carry) so your calculations have to be designed around it; it's not a drop-in replacement. See Mysticial's answer on [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866973/can-long-integer-routines-benefit-from-sse/8867025#8867025)

**Footnote 2**:  Unfortunately C does not provide carry-out from addition / subtraction, so it's not even convenient to write in C.  `sum = a+b` / `carry = sum<a` works for carry out when there's no carry in, but it's much harder to write a full adder in C.  And compiler typically make crap asm that doesn't just use native add-with-carry instructions on machines where they're available.  Extended-precision libraries for very big integers, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), are typically written in asm.

Comment: But can't I use that `__m256i` in my code?  I mean like `__m256i var1 = 0x7u; __m256i var2 = 0x8u; __m256i var3 = var2 & var1;`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito no, `__m256i` is meant for AVX2, which isn't a single 256-bit integer

Comment: @CacahueteFrito __m256i is basically 8 x 32bit integers (and some other variants). Those 8 integers are basically separate variables. Mixing and matching those ints (as you'd need for add-with-carry) comes with a  performance penalty. Communication across the 2x 128bit lanes in that type is even more expensive. 
You will need to find a C++ library that handles large ints using the standard 64bit/32bit integer types.

Comment: "You need a library that uses add-with-carry." You need a library, but how it is implemented is not that relevant. IIRC RISCV does not have add-with-carry, but you can still emulate a 256-bit integer type on it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: if it does not have add-with-carry natively, it will have to emulate it. But you do need add-with-carry, unless you have a native 256 bit type.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: MIPS doesn't have add-with-carry, neither do any other ISAs without a flags register.  That might include RISC-V, I forget.  This was an x86-64 question (which of course does have `adc`, but I expanded the wording anyway since I was phrasing it in more of an ISA neutral way anyway.

Comment: Does clang's `_ExtInt()` have a limit on the integer size?  I didn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: Answering my own question after some tests I did, yes, `_ExtInt()` is effectively a bignum type.  Kudos to Clang.  And the code is quite optimized :)

Comment: Clang seems to have dropped the support for the bit-length being greater than 128 starting from clang-14 (see [PR44994](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44994)).

Answer (score 6):

I did need "uint256_t" only while computing "f(x) = (x^2+a) mod n" in Pollard Rho algorithm. All variables outside function "f" are of builtin type __uint128_t.

I implemented uint256_t for that purpose simply as:

```
typedef __uint128_t uint256_t[2];
```

And then I implemented the functions needed for computing "f()":

```
__uint128_t set_128(unsigned long h, unsigned long l);
void set_256(uint256_t d, __uint128_t l, __uint128_t h);
void add_128(uint256_t d, uint256_t x, __uint128_t a);
void add_256(uint256_t d, uint256_t x, uint256_t a);
void shl_256(uint256_t d, long s);
void sqr_128(uint256_t d, __uint128_t x);
several print functions and macros for printing 128bit and 256bit numbers
__uint128_t mod_256(uint256_t x, __uint128_t n);
__uint128_t f(__uint128_t x);
```

Find the implementation in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/Hermann-SW/a20af17ee6666467fe0b5c573dae701d

I did benchmark my code against gmplib functions and achieved speedup over gmplib for all (after a lot of work), for details:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=311893&p=1873552#p1873552

Runtimes in nanoseconds for 1 million executions of a function:
[image]

Comment: For your benchmarks that show factors of 155k speedup for plain `__uint128_t`, its likely that most of the work optimized away or was hoisted out of the loop, but the gmp function calls were opaque to the optimizer.  It's impossible for a modern Intel/AMD CPU to loop faster than 1 iteration per clock cycle, or to do more than 1 scalar 64x64 => 128-bit `mul` per clock. If you're finding your code ran faster than that, it actually optimized away. (147 ns at 4GHz is only 588 cycles, totally implausible to do a million of anything without huge algorithmic optimization, i.e. not doing all the work)

Comment: See for example stuff like Google Benchmark's `DoNotOptimize()` function to make the compiler forget what it knows about a value.  Q&As: [Preventing compiler optimizations while benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40122141) / [Google Benchmark Frameworks DoNotOptimize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66795357)

Comment: Your speedups over GMP for your `uint256_t` do look more plausible, though: especially for squaring, three multiplies and a few adds aren't much work vs. GMP's general case with loops for variable length.  I'm still surprised it's as big as 20, though; perhaps *some* of the work still optimized away, or maybe there's more GMP overhead if you're not directly using `mpn_` functions.

Comment: You are right, compiler completely optimized away the multiplications: https://godbolt.org/z/584f4e9o4  I prefixed summation variable "s" with volatile, and assembler code completely changes: https://godbolt.org/z/WdnG458E1 Speedup of __uint128_t multiplication over gmplib "mpz_mul()" is now 14694553/1497909 = 9.8 times.

Comment: I prefixed __uint128_t variable "a" with volatile and did run benchmark again. Now speedup of uint256_t "sqr()" function over gmp_lib "mpz_mul()" is 17598169 / 3265127 = 5.39, so speedup 20 was wrong as well.

Comment: `volatile` might be hurting *more* than necessary, forcing extra loads as well as stopping the compiler from noticing that `a_high * a_low` is the same calculation as `a_low * a_high`, if you don't special-case it but instead rely on the compiler to notice the redundancy when inlining a normal multiply function with both args the same.  Or just general all around extra work from all the extra loads every time you mention `a`.  Microbenchmarking is hard: you have to check the asm to see if the work in the loop is exactly what you want to measure.  (Although DoNotOptimize can help a lot.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that "mpz_mul()" does special case handling identical operands as well (in mpz/mul.c):
...
   if (up == vp)
    {
      mpn_sqr (wp, up, usize);
      cy_limb = wp[wsize - 1];
    }
  else
...

Comment: GMP is an arbitrary-precision library, so obviously it's much slower than fixed-precision ones like [boost::multiprecision::uint256_t](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html), https://github.com/calccrypto/uint256_t or [ttmath:UInt<4>](https://www.ttmath.org/). You should compare with fixed-width libraries instead

Comment: Peter you are right again with "volatile might be hurting more than necessary", at least it depends where it is applied. I made the summation variable s volatile, and speedup did shrink to 9.8 times. Now instead I made variables a and b volatile, and speedup is now 13.2. That "s" works as expected can be verified by comparing sums reported in the end. Btw, what clobber does (potential use), I always do for summation variables by explicit use in print statement AFTER runtime has been determined, so that the print does not have effect on measured runtime.

Comment: phuclv, I did extend my performace test (summing 1 million squares of 128bit numbers) with ttmath. Compile instruction as well as test results in sqr.cpp gist: https://gist.github.com/Hermann-SW/83c8ab9e10a0bb64d770af543ed08445  To my surprise ttmath is slightly faster than gmplib with speedup 16054087 / 14803914 = 1.08. But I will go with my own uint256_t because that has speedup 16054087 / 2786120 = 5.76 over gmplib!

Comment: Because I run on a 64bit i7, ttmath::UInt<4> is 256bit number.

Comment: @HermannSW Can you please update your table with the new found "reasonable" speedup? It would be likely useful to use [table markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for that, too.

Answer (score -2):

You can see a litle about on source code of BITCOIN, they use a library to C Language. If Delphi/Pascal you can use the Fundamentals5 (https://github.com/fundamentalslib/fundamentals5). Looking for, is possible to find more options of third paid libraries. There are some solutions to more than 256 bits.