# turn off c++ loop optimization

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, microbenchmark

I am wondering how to turn off optimization for the following loop. I have searched and tried some flag but not working. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

int fun(int i) {return ++i;};

int main ()
{
    int res = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        res += fun(i);
    }
    std::cout << res;
}
```

-O1 will remove the loop and directly hard code the result. I would like to use -O3 but with this optimization turned off.

Comment: one way is to throw the res++ bugger in a virtual function or in some cases to call it via a function pointer. (compiler dependent)... If you want to turn off ops for a specific loop- might get tricky to the point of having to compile it in a separate file.

Comment: why would you want to run that useless loop in optimization mode? It's only for debugging purpose

Comment: Most compilers have a pragma to toggle optimizations in code: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas

Comment: Also, **what are you really trying to do**  by disabling a loop unroll optimization?  I wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is only for testing not for production:)

Comment: To be more specific, I am tring to performance test some code in the loop but compiler keeps remove the loop. I could use -O0 but it will turn off other optimization which I want to keep.

Comment: Have you tried to simply put the definition of `fun` into a separate compilation unit (source file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like Google Benchmark's `DoNotOptimize()` function. This function uses an empty `asm` block to lie to the compiler that the given variable was read from. Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66795357/1896169):

```cpp
template <class Tp>
[[gnu::always_inline]] inline void DoNotOptimize(Tp const& value) {
  asm volatile("" : : "r,m"(value) : "memory");
}

template <class Tp>
[[gnu::always_inline]] inline void DoNotOptimize(Tp& value) {
#if defined(__clang__)
  asm volatile("" : "+r,m"(value) : : "memory");
#else
  asm volatile("" : "+m,r"(value) : : "memory");
#endif
}
```

Then, you can lie to the compiler and tell it that `res` is read in each iteration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int res = 0;

    ::DoNotOptimize(res);
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        res++;
        ::DoNotOptimize(res);
    }
    std::cout << res;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/G7Ms6jTa5)

In `-O3`, the loop is unrolled, but `-O1` and `-O2` keep the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution definitely works but I think I over simplified my qusetion. So I updated it to call a function, which is still optimized to a hard coded number 50005000 by compiler. I also increased the iteration to prevent unrolling.

Comment: @frank I believe this solution still works: https://godbolt.org/z/EM1s7vco6