# DoNotOptimize from google benchmark vs volatile keyword for optimising out

Tags: c++, optimization, benchmarking, google-benchmark

This is my benchmark code sample :

Two ways of doing it :

```
volatile result = compute();
```

2nd way of doing it :

```
bool result = compute();
DoNotOptimize(result);
```

So i want to prevent the compiler to remove the compute() so which ones better ? Is it true that both have same effects ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795357/google-benchmark-frameworks-donotoptimize

Comment: Pretty similar except no store actually has to happen for `DoNotOptimize`, the compiler just needs to materialize the value in a register.  (And it's a compiler memory barrier for *other* variables, at least ones where references have escaped the function.)  IIRC, `DoNotOptimize` might use `"+r"` to make the compiler forget about the value of `result`, which is useful if you use it on a value that's used again later, not like the dead end use here.

Comment: thanks @PeterCordes ! I am a huge fan of you! if its okay with you can you please give me learning roadmap to the world of low latency development ? i am 18 year old working as an intern at an hft company. I want to increase my skill and value. i really love this field. advance thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `DoNotOptimize`. Here is the example when `volatile` does not prevent variable optimization out: https://quick-bench.com/q/tvsxD71u3d_PLgA9IKx7jwA6CLs.

The app is a single-threaded. The compiler knows `volatile std::string created_string` is never read.

`DoNotOptimize` forcly materializes `std::string created_string`, promising to the compiler later use of the variable. For details look at this perfect answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69288151/6752050.