# How to prevent a segment of Side Effect-Free code from being optimized away?

Tags: c++, c++14, benchmarking, compiler-optimization, microbenchmark

Consider a scenario where I have constructed a class T that represents large integers. This class T has an addition operator function.

```
class T {
public:
    T operator+(const T &other) const
}
```

In order to test its performance, I want to repeatedly
execute this function a sufficient number of times, record the total time elapsed, and then calculate the average time. Pseudo code is as follows:

```
T a, b;
Record the starting timestamp.
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
     a + b;
}
Record the ending timestamp.
Calculate the average time.
```

However, because the result of the a+b operation is not saved, and the operator+ function also does not modify a or b in any way, a + b; is Side Effect-Free code and will be optimized away by the compiler. One feasible solution is to change

```
 a + b;
```

to

```
T t = a + b;

store t somewhere
```

However, this would introduce calls to the copy constructor and increase the overhead of storing t, making the timing measurement less accurate. Is there a way to tell the compiler not to optimize away a+b;?

Comment: I just want to prevent the line a + b; from being optimized out while retaining other optimizations, as I want to measure the performance achievable by the operator+ function with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Use [nanobench](https://nanobench.ankerl.com/reference.html)  header file only library for benchmarking and its [doNotOptimizeAway](https://nanobench.ankerl.com/reference.html#donotoptimizeaway)

Comment: Looks like it should be sufficient to disable LTO in this case, assuming that the operator is compiled in a different TU than the code that calls it.  Then your compiler will be unaware that it's side-effect-free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a side-effect that requires the result, e.g. GNU C `asm volatile("" :: "r"(value))` is `volatile` so can't be optimized away, and requires the value to exist in a register.  But compiles to zero asm instructions.

OTOH, that would still allow hoisting the `a+b` computation out of the loop, so you also need to make the compiler forget about the values of `a` and `b` every iteration, e.g. with `asm("" : "+g"(a), "+g"(b))` to tell the compiler both variables are read/write operands that the asm statement modifies.  This might not be compatible with `const`.  Perhaps with a BigInt that only fits in memory, you could take pointers to the locals and use a `"memory"` clobber to make the compiler assume the data is modified even though you only have `const` references.

You'd have to check the asm to make sure that didn't introduce extra store/reloads.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)).  `"memory"` clobbers don't affect local vars whose address hasn't been taken, but passing the addresses as input operands to an `asm` statement should make it respect them.

Various `DoNotOptimize` implementations use GNU C inline asm that way `#ifdef __GNUC__`.  Like [nanobench's `doNotOptimizeAway`](https://nanobench.ankerl.com/reference.html#donotoptimizeaway), and Google::Benchmark, see related Q&As:  ([Google Benchmark Frameworks DoNotOptimize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66795357) / [and another re: the `"memory"` clobber in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69287053)). ISO C++ doesn't have a portable way to do that, so for example with MSVC they might store a value to a `volatile int sink` dummy variable.

But introducing a store/reload in a loop-carried dependency chain could be a huge slowdown like a debug build (unlike just storing the same location repeatedly which L1d cache can absorb) so there's no good portable equivalent for the `"+g"(var)` constraint to make the compiler assume the value has been modified without actually running any instructions.

`"g"` lets the compiler pick memory or register at its option.  But clang might always prefer memory, so `"+r,m"` can work around that.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I can think of is to set the optimization level to zero through the compiler flag `-O0`

[Here's a simple demo using Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rxMsTGcje)

When set to zero `-O0` it takes 10180 time units.

When set to three `-O3`it takes only 90 time units.

*You may also inspect the generated assembly code.*

Comment: Benchmarking with optimization disabled is pointless, with different bottlenecks from optimized code (often store-forwarding latency, or in C++, non-inlined calls to tiny functions), so whatever small-scale local effect you were trying to measure isn't even there anymore.  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) / [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) / [How can I optimize these loops (with compiler optimization disabled)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001196)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).