# Weird behavior in google benchmark when using benchmark::DoNotOptimize()

Tags: c++, gcc, google-benchmark

Test program:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

void BM_stdPowSimple(benchmark::State& state)
{
    const double n = 2.00;
    double ret = std::pow(10, n);
    printf("Before  %f  %f\n", n, ret);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        printf("Step 1  %f\n", ret);
        ret = std::pow(10, n);
        printf("Step 2  %f\n", ret);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ret);
        printf("Step 3  %f\n", ret);
    }
    printf("After   %f  %f\n", n, ret);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_stdPowSimple)->Iterations(1);
```

Output:

```
Before  2.000000  100.000000
Step 1  100.000000
Step 2  100.000000
Step 3  0.000000
After   2.000000  0.000000
```

`ret` should always be 100, but it become zero after `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ret);`.

If I comment `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ret);`, works as expect:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

void BM_stdPowSimple(benchmark::State& state)
{
    const double n = 2.00;
    double ret = std::pow(10, n);
    printf("Before  %f  %f\n", n, ret);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        printf("Step 1  %f\n", ret);
        ret = std::pow(10, n);
        printf("Step 2  %f\n", ret);
        // benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ret);
        printf("Step 3  %f\n", ret);
    }
    printf("After   %f  %f\n", n, ret);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_stdPowSimple)->Iterations(1);
```

```
Before  2.000000  100.000000
Step 1  100.000000
Step 2  100.000000
Step 3  100.000000
After   2.000000  100.000000
```

Or if I declare `ret` as `volatile double`, the result is correct too:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

void BM_stdPowSimple(benchmark::State& state)
{
    const double n = 2.00;
    volatile double ret = std::pow(10, n);
    printf("Before  %f  %f\n", n, ret);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        printf("Step 1  %f\n", ret);
        ret = std::pow(10, n);
        printf("Step 2  %f\n", ret);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ret);
        printf("Step 3  %f\n", ret);
    }
    printf("After   %f  %f\n", n, ret);
}
BENCHMARK(BM_stdPowSimple)->Iterations(1);
```

```
Before  2.000000  100.000000
Step 1  100.000000
Step 2  100.000000
Step 3  100.000000
After   2.000000  100.000000
```

---

Compiler: g++ (GCC) 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-4)

`benchmark::DoNotOptimize()` implementation:

```cpp
template <class Tp>
inline BENCHMARK_ALWAYS_INLINE
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<Tp>::value &&
                            (sizeof(Tp) <= sizeof(Tp*))>::type
    DoNotOptimize(Tp& value) {
  asm volatile("" : "+m,r"(value) : : "memory");
}
```

---

I'm not sure whether it's about google benchmark or g++ compiler. `DoNotOptimize()` function is very simple, I don't understand why adding it would lead to the incorrect result.

Comment: FWIW: this does not happen on clang. the `asm` statement seems to cause gcc to load a value from the stack which was never written to, where clang actually placed the value of `ret` there before.

Comment: Here's a more minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/99nanjKn8

Comment: @perivesta I think it's a bug in gcc?

Comment: Might be, I sadly don't know enough about asm to fully get the semantics of that statement. This might help tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69288151/10362622

Comment: I find seems only `double` has this problem, chaning it to `int` works well.