# How to tell GCC/Clang optimizer to generate specific sequence of operations

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, loop-unrolling

I have a loop that needs to execute sequences of operations in a specific order. What I am doing here is manually unrolling the loop a number of times:

```
loop
{
    delta = get_delta();
    sum1 += delta;
    sum2 += delta;
    sum3 += delta;

    delta = get_delta();
    sum1 += delta;
    sum2 += delta;
    sum3 += delta;
}
```

Looking at the generated assembly code, sometimes compilers optimize this loop into something like this:

```
loop
{
    delta1 = get_delta();
    delta2 = get_delta();
    delta_sum = delta1 + delta2;

    sum1 += delta_sum;
    sum2 += delta_sum;
    sum3 += delta_sum;
}
```

I don't want this to happen, as the behavior does not quite replicate loop unrolling. I've been looking into inline assembly hints via `__asm__` keyword, but can't quite get this to work reliably. I also don't want to use `volatile` variables as this causes loads from memory, rather than using registers. Changing optimization flags at build to `-O0` or `-O1` is not ideal, as this is not guaranteed to always produce consistent results with different compiler versions, etc.

Does anyone know of any tricks I can use with `__asm__` or similar, so that I can unroll the loop in exactly the sequence how it is written in the source code, without having to resort to writing assembly code?

Comment: To answer this question we need to know why the order of operations matters.

Comment: @tkausl I already explained, this is part of loop unrolling, hence I need to execute exactly the same sequence several times, without transforming it into something else. This is part of timing characteristics and should provide consistent execution with regard to the number of times the loop is unrolled.

Comment: Does this run on some sort of microprocessor? If you require specific timing characteristic, C is the wrong language and you should use assembly instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent GCC optimizing some statements in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-can-i-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

Comment: (I may be wrong about this being a duplicate, but it would be helpful if you make sure your question addresses how the linked question does or doesn't address your issue.)

Comment: But if you say you need "consistent results" (as-in: generates the precise assembly for all versions of the complier), I don't see how you avoid writing it in assembly. You may investigate compiler intrinsics, which are a bit friendlier to use than raw assembly. As an example for x86: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html  (Though in my experience, by the time I pull out intrinsics, I usually find it better just to write the stupid assembly...)

Comment: Why does timing matter to your program?  Is it for security reasons (constant time evaluation to prevent side-channel attacks)?  Is it for a hard realtime system?  Something else?

Comment: You seem to have some kind of underlying grand objective that you're not disclosing to us. Why does it matter if the order of operations does not exactly correspond to a direct loop unrolling? Were I unrolling your loop by hand, I'd certainly do something along the lines of what you observe the compiler doing automatically.

Comment: I know how to change optimizations, however with different compilers from different vendors, there is no consistent optimization flag that disables this specific loop transformation. So I can build a fragment of code with `-O0` but this is very crude. What I am looking for is some compiler `pragma` or `__asm__` syntax to give the optimizer a strong hint not to mess with the order of my operations. It doesn't matter why consistent timing matters for me, it's too long of a subject to go into the actual details.

Comment: Pragmas are implementation-specific -- that is the whole point of them.  Inline assembly too, and even more so because syntax and dialect not only varies among C implementations, but across hardware architectures, too.

Comment: Are the `sumN` variables local to the function where this loop appears or are they file scope variables (either local to the TU — `static`  — or global)?  Does the `get_delta()` function make use of the `sumN` variables?  Why do you need 3 variables which are kept in sync by this loop?  (Presumably, there is other code which sometimes modifies a subset of the three variables, but it would help to know that.). Have you considered putting the 4 lines of code into a (`static inline`) function?  I'm not convinced that would fake out the optimizer, but it's worth a mention.

Comment: I don't believe there is a portable way to tell all compliant C compilers that they must avoid a specific optimization that only impacts the number of operations required. You can mark values with things like `volatile` to prevent *incorrect* optimizations (i.e. ones that rely on a value being static when it is not). But what you're asking for I don't believe is anywhere in the C standard, so it cannot be portable. The right approach IMO would be write the assembly for each supported platform (not inline; I'd probably write it as `.s` files and assemble it).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler All variables are local to a function in which the loop executes. Please don't read too much into the code, this is just an example to illustrate how the optimizer transforms the loop. As to why I need multiple variables like in my example, I'm trying to measure CPU pipelining and out of order execution of various operations on different platforms.

Comment: You might be able to use Google `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize` ([Google Benchmark Frameworks DoNotOptimize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66795357)) or something similar to force the compiler to materialize the first three `sum` results.  Perhaps with a `"+r"` constraint to tell the compiler the asm statement modifies the value (even though it doesn't).  With a `"memory"` clobber, probably can get it to do that before the second call to `get_delta()`.  So you'd be using inline asm, but not for actual instructions, just to create extra dependencies the optimizer has to respect.

Comment: Manual loop unrolling is often a waste of time with modern optimising compilers,  accurate branch prediction is able to equal or sometimes beat having the code duplicated. Try it without loop unrolling and see if is still fast enough. Even then I expect the next get_delta() starts to execute before the last of the previous 3 additions has completed. Out of order execution makes it tricky to predict exactly what has completed at any given moment in time. Will _mm_fence() not do what you want? (at least on the Intel platform) [fence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593961/)

Comment: @MartinBrown Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think memory fencing is going to help here. First instruction `delta = get_delta()` loads a value from memory into a register. The next three instructions use `delta` register to execute operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. The objective is not just to execute these statements "fast enough", but to execute them consistently in the same order across different platforms. I can achieve that by disabling automatic loop unrolling, but this adds the overhead of loop decrement and jump instructions. Unrolling loop minimizes that.

Comment: @MilhouseVanhouten are you sure that there is a loop overhead on modern CPUs? Nothing in the loop depends on the loop counter and branch prediction will be wrong at most twice in every execution. Instruction cache locality can make a lot of difference. Surely on different compilers and CPUs you want to benchmark what performance the compiler -O3 plus CPU can obtain - you don't really care about the mechanics provided that the final result is the same (and sometimes it isn't not all rearrangements are safe).

Comment: @MartinBrown Yes I'm pretty sure, every loop has overheads, on some platforms it is more significant than on the others. Measuring this overhead is very tricky, i.e. you can't just measure empty `while (counter-- != 0) {__asm__ volatile("" : "+g" (counter));}` due to pipelining and multiple integer execution units. Some processors can execute multiple instruction in parallel, which skews such measurements when you add code inside the loop. The only way to minimize this overhead is to unroll the loop. I may have found a solution to the original question. I will post the answer if it works.

Comment: @MartinBrown: For loops that bottleneck on front-end bandwidth (getting instructions fetched and allocated/renamed into the out-of-order back-end), or on back-end execution units, then yes, loop overhead is still a thing.  e.g. Skylake's front-end is 4 uops wide, and the `dec / jnz` at the bottom of a loop costs 1 of those uops.  And with arrays, there's often a separate pointer increment.  e.g. in [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61122144) , the AVX2 part of my answer has a 9 uop loop that benefits from unrolling.

Comment: @MartinBrown: Branch prediction just avoids stalling the front-end for every branch, and makes out-of-order exec across loop iterations possible.  You still have to actually execute the branch instruction to confirm the prediction.  Anyway, another case of loops that often bottleneck on the front-end are histograms, if the count array is small enough to fit in cache.  [Suggestions on further optimising this chi-square function using SSE2 intrinsics](//stackoverflow.com/q/77037432) has some uop counting an analysis.  (I'm sure I've written some simpler answers, but google didn't find them.)

Comment: Also more directly looking at performance bottlenecks in tiny loops: [Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39311872) (not as much on Intel Haswell and later as in Sandybridge.)  BTW, clang defaults to unrolling tiny loops, by 4 or even 8 for the tiniest, or only by 2 for less-tiny loops.  GCC's default is `-fno-unroll-loops` unless you enable profile-guided optimization.

Comment: @PeterCordes  That's interesting and very slick if the histogram is small enough! Empirically I have found that one branch statement almost comes for free provided that the branching is predictable (most of my problems the branch taken changes once or possibly twice) over an extended period. Nesting two conditionals also doesn't seem to incur a performance hit on the best code generators now (eg Intel 2022) provided that there is sufficient work to do in each of the branches (and with my slowly changing branch taken). If branch to be taken is unpredictable then I guess all bets are off.

Comment: @MartinBrown: Like I said it's not always about *prediction*, it's about getting those branch instructions (and pointer increments) through the front end once per every 1, 2, or 4 copies of the loop body.  If you aren't stalling on memory bandwidth, it's quite possible to bottleneck on front-end instruction throughput of 4 uops per clock on Skylake. (5 on Ice Lake, 6 on Alder Lake, making this bottleneck less likely).

Comment: Also there's latency: if you're doing `sum += arr[i]`, with integer (1 cycle latency) you can get at best 1 add per clock, whether that's SIMD or scalar.  But your CPU is capable of 2 loads per clock, or in Alder Lake, 3 SIMD int load+add / clock.  So you or the compiler need sum1, sum2, sum3 etc.  This is a much bigger deal with floating point where latencies are higher, e.g. for an FP dot product or sum of an array: [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527)

Comment: (If your data isn't hot in L1d cache, usually L2 bandwidth is something like 1x 256-bit vector per clock, in which case unrolling with multiple accumulators only helps for FP or I guess scalar integer, not SIMD integer with AVX2).

Comment: @PeterCordes The reduced performance thing vs uop count is even more interesting to me. I have a weird speed up question that will take some effort to turn into an MRE. The code gets more complex with each refinement beyond NR(D_2) and Halley(D_3) but for some problems and using the Intel compiler D_5 is inexplicably fastest! This was a big surprise! (loop time approx 140-200 uops). Hints of the same with GCC but it is still some way off the pace compared to Intel - any suggestions for more obscure go faster FP options? I've tried the obvious ones but I'm a complete novice on GCC.

Comment: @MartinBrown: With GCC, `-ffast-math` enables everything, I think.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath .  GCC is bad at unrolling with multiple accumulators: even if you tell it to unroll (like with `-funroll-loop -funroll-all-loops`), it just adds into the same register multiple times in the asm loop, unlike clang `-ffast-math`.  So if FP latency was a bottleneck, you might need manual unrolling (and maybe manual vectorization).  If you're on SKL/SKX-family, [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646)

Comment: @MartinBrown: Profile-guided optimization is also worth trying, if you aren't already.  Just knowing that a loop is hot might make GCC try harder than normal, and make better unrolling decisions.  (And LTO if your hot loops have any function calls that don't get inlined, or if inlining can give better value-range info for loop-invariants.)  BTW, I forgot to mention yesterday, but loop-buffer sizes are like 70 uops on Ice Lake, the IDQ size. (https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/sunny_cove#Key_changes_from_Palm_Cove.2FSkylake).  The uop cache is much larger.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with various `__asm__ volatile ()` statements and different compiler optimization options, it became clear that loop unrolling, either automatically or manually, has too many side effects. Compilers perform all sorts of code optimizations and eliminations, which result in very different code constructs.

To achieve consistent results with timing loops, the following should be done:

1. Completely disable loop unrolling for specific translation units with `_Pragma ("GCC unroll 1")` and `-fno-unroll-loops`.
2. Increase the number of instructions inside the loop, in order to reduce loop overhead skewing the measurements with large number of loop iterations.
3. Don't use `-O0` or similar, this is too crude and disables many other useful optimizations.