# Generate 128 bit(uint128_t) randomly in c++ via boost::random

Tags: c++, boost, random

How to generate a 128 bit number in c++ via boost::random. I have read the official doc. The uniform_int_distribution could only generate 64 bit(length of int).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can generate two 64bit numbers, and conbine them into a 128bit number.

Comment: Does the number still random generated in this way?@JunGe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jun Ge said you could combine two 64 bit integers into a 128 bit integer.  The C++ spec does not include 128 bit integers, so you need to find an alternative way. Maybe your compilers has them. You use boost::random so I assume you can use boost::multiprecision.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int128_t int64left = CreateRandomInt64ViaBoost()
int128_t int64right = CreateRandomInt64ViaBoost()

int128_t randomInt = int64left << 64 | int64right;
```

Targeting one of your comments earlier: yes this is a completely random 128 bit int, you just generate it in two steps.