# How to define 128 bit UUID in arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question for how to define BLE 128 bit service UUID in arduino.

I can see 16 bit UUID in example like this:

## define SERVICE_UUID_BATTERY (0x180F)

but how to define the 128 bit UUID in arduino?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be defined this way:

```
/* 00000000-ABCD-FEED-F00D-012345678900 decided as custom ID. */
uint8_t UUID[] = { 0x00, 0x89, 0x67, 0x45, 0x23, 0x01, 0x0D,0xF0, 0xED, 0xFE,     0xCD, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As Arduino is based on C++, I don't think this is possible because :

> GCC does have an uint128_t/int128_t type, starting from version
>   4.something (not sure here). I do seem to recall, however, that there was a __int128_t def before that.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc)

But you can try to have a look at this thread : [Representing 128-bit numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188939/representing-128-bit-numbers-in-c)

Maybe you can use this librairie in Arduino...

Comment: Thanks Raphael, let me try the library.

Comment: hi Raphael, i think i found the answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: GCC only defines 128-bit integer types on 64-bit targets (where it takes 2 registers).  Arduino is AVR, where __int128 would take 16 registers.  Or 32-bit ARM, but not AArch64.