# avoiding overflow while multiplying very large integer in c++

Tags: c++, integer, largenumber

The other day I was solving one   multiplication programming problem in which multiplicand(a1,a2,..an) can be 1<= ai <= 10^9 . So my question is how to multiply those numbers so that they'll always remain in (long long) range in C++.

Should I use any kind of mod(like 10^9+7) but it's not mentioned in question whether to use it or not?

I used normal multiplication with/without mod 10^9+7 only to vain.
Also tried my luck with **Russian Peasant Multiplication** with mod 10^9+7

```
long long mulmod(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long res = 0; // Initialize result
    a = a % mod;
    while (b > 0)
    {
        // If b is odd, add 'a' to result
        if (b % 2 == 1)
            res = (res + a) % mod;

        // Multiply 'a' with 2
        a = (a * 2) % mod;

        // Divide b by 2
        b /= 2;
    }

    // Return result
    return (res % mod);
}
```

still no accepted solution. :-(

Edit 1: ll to long long.

Comment: "still no accepted solution" - How if you tagged your question with the wrong language?

Comment: c++ ? yeah i'm doin it  in c++.

Comment: well, what would you LIKE it to do if it goes out of range?  Given that it's UB for it to go out of range you should be avoiding that situation where you can anyway.

Comment: Instead of `a * 2` you need to perform an operation which won't overflow. I would say `a + a` with some modified `a` value.

Comment: I didn't get the question. If you are multiplying two"large" integers and their product actually exceeds the type (int OR long), how can you avoid it?

Comment: @MayurK that's what i'm asking. Answer is overflowing for sure. then how'd u  make it to fit it in long long range.

Comment: "My number doesn't fit in a long long, how do I make it fit in a long long?" is the question I'm currently seeing ... I think you need to revisit what you want to ask.

Comment: @UKMonkey u got it right buddy.

Comment: Short answer - you don't.  Long answer - you make a class, and keep the exponent as one variable, and some digits on another, and then implement all the operations for your new class.

Comment: I think i got my answer .Thank u all for helping. :-)

Comment: You tagged as C until I edited. Next time use the correct tag from the start.

Comment: @Olaf a haven't i used the tag C++?

Comment: Read the history!

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be either

- Using wider integers (128+), which has already been solved: [representing 128 bit numbers in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188939/representing-128-bit-numbers-in-c)
- Using floating point real numbers, where you lose accuracy in exchange of flexibility.